# Passing variables from parent function to child function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
function parent(one,two,three,yahoo) {
  blabla
  blabla
  function(what,where,how,one,two) {
     blabla
     //usage of what, where, how, one, two
     blabla
  }
  blabla
  blabla
}
```

So, as you can see, I want to pass the "one" and "two" from "parent" to "child".

How can I achieve this in cross-browser way, please?

Comment: You don't need to pass them. All the parent function's variables are in the scope of the child function.

Comment: Please structure you question properly. And yes, all parent scope variables are available in the embedded child scope.

Comment: parent function parameters are available to child function. Just don't create variables, parameters that have the same name as parent's parameters you want to use (they will shadow them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent function's scope includes child functions, so the child can access them without them being passed. Just leave them out of the parameter list.

```
function parent(one,two,three,yahoo) {
  blabla
  blabla
  function(what,where,how) {
     blabla
     //usage of what, where, how, one, two
     blabla
  }
  blabla
  blabla
}
```

For more info, see [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript?s=1|6.5578)

Answer (score 0):

```
function parent(one,two,three,yahoo) {
 function a (what,where,how,one,two) {
console.log(one + two);
 }
  a(1,2,3,this.one,this.two);

}

parent(1,2,3,4);
```

Use 'this' to pass the parameters of the parent function.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your child function, you can call your parent variables wiothout passing them as a parameter in your child function...

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kftj5ct/)

```
function parent(one,two,three,yahoo) {
 console.log(one);
 console.log(two);
 console.log(three);
 console.log(yahoo);

  function child(what,where,how) {
 console.log(one);
 console.log(two); 
 console.log(what);
 console.log(where); 
 console.log(how);
  }

  child("what","where","how");
}

parent("1","2","3","yahoo");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass them. Parent functions variable are accessible by the child function by default

```js
var parent=function(one) {
  //something
  var child=function(one){
    alert(one);
  }
  child(one);
}

parent("this is the parent variable to child scope.");
```

Comment: You are passing the variables here, which you say not to do, instead of implying them with scope.